# How should I close a session inherited in a multiprocessing.Process that doesn't need it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, orm, sqlalchemy

In the main process, I create a `scoped_session` object as follows:

```
self.session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False, autocommit=False))
```

Later the main process starts several subprocesses using the `multiprocessing` module, among which some don't need the `Session`:

```
...
logger = mp.Process(target=self._logger, qw, ql, log_init))
logger.start()
...
```

Now, I have read in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing) that subprocesses should call `Engine.dispose()` on the `Engine` to get their own connections:

```
self.session.get_bind().dispose()
```

Also, without the above call to `Engine.dispose()`, a call to `self.session.remove()` would release the parent processes' connection resources?

How should I safely close sessions not needed in child processes, so that their resources are released?

Also, the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#engine-disposal) say that: "*Database connections generally do not travel across process boundaries.*" Isn't that false as TCP connections are represented as file descriptors, which work across process boundaries?

> When a program uses multiprocessing or fork(), and an Engine object is
>   copied to the child process, Engine.dispose() should be called so that
>   the engine creates brand new database connections local to that fork.
>   Database connections generally do not travel across process
>   boundaries.